# codeigniter shows stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto this error on sendmail?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendmail

I am trying to send email with code igniter with xampp server on my local machine but its not working. it shows me some errors that i searched alot on net but i am helpless now all solutions that i tried are failed for me.

below are my 3 errors:

`Message: stream_socket_client(): SSL: The operation completed successfully.`

`Message: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto`

`Message: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Unknown error)`

this is my php code:

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '587',
        'smtp_user' => 'mygmailid@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxmypassword',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
                    );
        $message = '';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('mygmailid@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to('mygmailid@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
        $this->email->message($message);
      if($this->email->send())
        {
          echo 'Email sent.';
        }
     else
        {
         show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
```

on print_debugger i get this error too:

`The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

`This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.`

please guide me with proper solution.

Comment: SSL is port 465 not 587 (587 is for TLS)

Comment: port is 587 on my local machine

Comment: You're trying to connect to google servers right? `'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'` You see how you're going via SSL? You're getting a `unable to connect to` error because you have your methods mixed up

Comment: Also there is one setting available in GMail to enable low security app, pls check that once as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You email config should look something like this:

```
$config = Array(
  'protocol'  => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'YOUR_USERNAME',
  'smtp_pass' => 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
  'mailtype'  => 'html',
  'charset'   => 'utf-8',
  'newline'   => "\r\n",
  'wordwrap'  => TRUE,
);
```

And like Sandeep J Patel said in his comment, you will also need to enable access for less secure apps in your gmail account settings.

See their help page about that: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en